# Por quê View não enxerga o arquivo javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como fazer a `view` executar o arquivo javascript: `novo.js`

**Estrutura de diretórios:** 
Views > Produto > js > novo.js

**Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**View Produto.cshtml**:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

    @section scripts{

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Produto/js/novo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

        <script src="~/Views/Produto/js/novo.js"></script>
    }
```

**Arquivo novo.js:**

```
$(function () {
    console.log("olá");
});
```

Comment: Se você olhar o na aba Source da devtools do seu navegador aparece o arquivo novo.js

Comment: Ok @Thales Morais vou editar o post e melhorar a pergunta alterei onde ta escrito enxergar para executar.

Comment: Ok, eu entendi a sua pergunta. A questão é que se faz necessario identicar se o arquivo está carregando no seu browser. Pois se não estiver existe algo errado no middleware usado para isto ou algo do tipo. Caso não o erro está no caminho para os scipt

Comment: Importante lembrar de colocar o middleware no seu app.js para o arquivo identificar o arquivo estatico. Editei minha resposta para ficar mais claro

Comment: @Thales Morais como pode ver o exemplo que postei é uma execução de uma função jquery muito simples, o código fonte é bem customizado e detalhe caso eu coloco o arquivo novo.js na pasta padrão criada pelo Visual Studio: Content/Scripts funciona normalment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução nesse post: [Where to put view-specific javascript files in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604883/where-to-put-view-specific-javascript-files-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), tive que acrescentar algumas tags no arquivo web.config.

Answer (score 0):

adicione isso no webConfig, no meu resolveu

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
        <add path="*.css" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <!-- other content here -->
</system.web>
```

Answer (score -1):

Se você estiver usando o node.js com express certifique-se de ter colocado o novo.js como arquivo static como abaixo:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js/novo.js')))
```

E é importante que o arquivo tenha carregado no browser do cliente. Por esse motivo certifique-se de que seu novo.js está carregando na aba source da devtools do seu navegador. Se estiver significa que seu arquivo está correto e o erro está na view se não significa que o erro está no seu app.js provavelmente o arquivo não está para ficar statico no cliente.

Comment: obrigado mas não resolveu

Comment: Editei a resposta para ficar mais claro

Comment: Olá Thales Morais obrigado mas eu não estou usando nodes.js.